# React - Native : possible unhandled promise rejection (id:120)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to ask the solution for my problem. I have a code for countdown timer. When i create a code countdown timer without storing the variabel to my storage it's not gave me a problem. but, when i adding the code for storing di counter to the storage i have a problem warning "possible unhandled promise rejection (id:120)" and this is not storing the value in the variable counter. How to solve this problem when the counter is decrease, and every counter decreasing, it will store to my storage? here my code below

```js
componentDidMount = async() =>{
    this.hitungMundur()
  }

  async hitungMundur(){
    let counter = 10

    const interval = setInterval(async() =>{
      console.log(counter)
      counter--

      await AsyncStorage.setItem('durasi', counter)
      if(counter < 0){
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log('stoped')
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only set strings value in AsyncStorage
Please check the documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html#setitem)

await AsyncStorage.setItem('durasi', String(counter))

Answer (score 3):

you should wrap `await AsyncStorage.setItem('durasi', counter)` inside `try` block and `catch` if promise rejected

```
 try { await AsyncStorage.setItem('durasi', counter) }
 catch (err) { console.log(err) }
```